# How do I cross reference lists in Microsoft Excel and use results to add to a counter?

Tags: excel

I have a list of first names, last names, and group in an excel spreadsheet.  People swipe ID's to take attendance and first names and last names are returned to me.

I want to take the names that were swiped in, compare first name and then compare last name (or both at the same time if that's possible - they're in separate columns) and if it matches I want to compare what group they're in to a list of groups and add one point to that groups total.

I've tried a few methods, and even tried playing with some VB (which i'm not learned in) but can't figure it out.

Comment: I can't explain far, but VLOOKUP may be the solution you're looking for.  With that you should be able to cross reference a value from a list, and do what you will with the results.

Comment: does the name appear in the same place in the sheet, or does it create a list one under the other?

Comment: the names will appear in a different sheet and need to be moved into the sheet that it will be compared to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you...

You will need 3 tables:

- TABLE 1: Swipe list plus couple extra columns
- TABLE 2: Groups with fullname and group
- TABLE 3: Results

[image]

Formula 1:

```
=A5 & " " & B5
```

Formula 2:

```
=vlookup(C5, $F:$G, 2, 0)
```

Formula 3:

```
=countif($D:$D, I5)
```

The only issue with this approach is that there couldn't be repeated names in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

use an Index/Match combination to look up the group for the concatenation of first name and last name. Then use a pivot table to count the groups

[image]

In this screenshot, every swipe is recorded in the table that starts in A2. First and last name are in separate columns. The formula to look up the group name in the table with all the names and groups is in C3 and copied down:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$7,MATCH(A3&B3,INDEX($F$2:$F$7&$G$2:$G$7,0),0))
```

Build a pivot table based on the Swipe list table. Drag the group lookup into the row area, and drag it again into the Values area to count. When a new name is added to the Swipe list table, the formula in column C will automatically be applied. Refresh the pivot table to update.

As an alternative, you can build a manual list of groups and use a formula. Type the group names in a column, for example starting in F19. Then in G19 use

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,F19)
```

Copy down.